# Trying to animate a growing and shrinking filament, with a branch

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

Basically, the parent filament grows and shrinks from an initial point in space. When it reaches a threshold length(in the code I have provided, it corresponds to coordinates = (X = 8, X =8)). At this point, the branch starts to grow from (8,8). The branch grows and shrinks similarly to the parent, the difference is that its starting point is (8,8) as compared to (1,1) for the parent.(Although I start the branch from (1,1), that is just to have the list lengths equal for the animation)

The bigger problem is that I have several such parent filaments in my code growing at different angles, and when each of them cross a threshold length, a branch occurs at a random angle. Also if the parent shrinks back to a length less than the threshold, the branch disappears(or in a easy way, the coordinates of the branch are the same as the parent.).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,11,10,11,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,13] #parent x coord
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,11,10,11,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,13] #parent y coord

X1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,5,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,5,4,3] #branch x coord
Y1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,12,12,11,10,9,8,9,10,11,12,13] #branch y coord

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlim([0, 20])
ax.set_ylim([-1.1, 20])

graph1, = ax.plot([], [], color = 'green')
graph2, = ax.plot([], [], color = 'green')
dot1, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='red', markersize = 5)

dot2, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='green', markersize = 5)
def oj(i):

    graph1.set_data([X[0],X[i]],[Y[0],Y[i]]) ## for the parent this works as I want it grow and shrink without any trace

    graph2.set_data(X1[:i+1],Y1[:i+1]) # for the branch I can't use the same code as that for graph1 as I want it to be attached at (8,8) and grow from or shrink to that poin
    dot1.set_data(X[i],Y[i]) # this shows how the tip of the parent filament animates

    dot2.set_data(X1[i],Y1[i]) #this shows the tip of the branch which I face a difficulty in animating as it traces back instead of showing a shrink 
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, oj, frames=len(X), interval=1000, repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your question so that it's clearer what is going wrong / what part you're still needing? Right now your code runs fine and shows growing/shrinking so I don't know what the question is! :-)

Comment: The problem is with the shrinking of the branch. It's the green dot which represents the tip of the filament, it should shrink similarly to the parent(red dot is the parent's tip). For the parent, I can use '' graph1.set_data([X[0],X[i]],[Y[0],Y[i]]) '', but can't use the same for the branch. What I am using for the branch simply retraces the already drawn line as the tip moves back to the point of origin of the branch((8,8)). I want that to shrink the same way as the parent.

Comment: Since you said below that you won't know *when* to expect branching, I'd try to store the last known position of each branch at each iteration in a global dictionary (e.g. `coor_dict={'branch_0':{'current':[1,3],'children':['branch_1','branch_3'],'last_shown_frame':14},'branch_1'{'current':[3,6],….}}} ` and the work out everything else in *relative coordinates*, i.e `dx,dy=3,-1` steps. If you label your plot lines accordingly, you should be able to define a function with arguments `func(branch_label,new_pos=[3,-1]` which updates the respective element.

Comment: From what you posted above, I understand that you mean to store the position of the branch([1,3],[3,6] are the branch positions?). However, the branch position remains the same(8,8), which defines a certain length of the filament from its starting point, at which the branch occurs. What I don't know is the index i at  which the branch might occur, as the filament during the animation can grow greater than this length leading to a branch, then shrink to length less than that, leading to the branch going off, then again growing tp the threshold length, and again growing a branch.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually keep the same strategy you used for the main branch, but introduce a parameter indicating at which step the branching should occur and work from there:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,11,10,11,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,13] #parent x coord
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,11,10,11,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,13] #parent y coord

X1 = [7,6,5,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,5,4,3] #branch x coord
Y1 = [9,10,11,12,12,12,11,10,9,8,9,10,11,12,13] #branch y coord

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlim([0, 20])
ax.set_ylim([-1.1, 20])

graph1, = ax.plot([], [], color = 'green')
graph2, = ax.plot([], [], color = 'green')
dot1, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='red', markersize = 5)
dot2, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='green', markersize = 5)
ttl = ax.set_title('')

def oj(i, branch_point):
    ttl.set_text('i={:d}'.format(i))
    graph1.set_data([X[0],X[i]],[Y[0],Y[i]]) ## for the parent this works as I want it grow and shrink without any trace
    dot1.set_data(X[i],Y[i]) # this shows how the tip of the parent filament animates
    if i>branch_point:
        graph2.set_data([X[branch_point],X1[i-branch_point-1]],[Y[branch_point],Y1[i-branch_point-1]]) # for the branch I can't use the same code as that for graph1 as I want it to be attached at (8,8) and grow from or shrink to that poin
        dot2.set_data(X1[i-branch_point-1],Y1[i-branch_point-1]) #this shows the tip of the branch which I face a difficulty in animating as it traces back instead of showing a shrink 
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, oj, frames=len(X), interval=1000, repeat=False, fargs=(7,))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This works for a simple case where I have hypothetical data as above. However, I want to write a code which is more generalized, by which I mean that I don't know at what index 'i' the branch occurs. The problem I am working on has coordinates changing randomly, i.e., at each iteration, the filament may either grow or stay at the same length or shrink, one of which is chosen randomly. Also, it is possible that there are multiple instances when a branch may occur and then disappear if the length< threshold and then again branch out if length>threshold at a later iteration.